# Can't dup FalseClass error with Dynamoid and Ruby on Rails over Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, amazon-dynamodb

**Hi,**

I'm using Ruby on Rails 5 and DynamoDB to persist my data and, in order to do this, i'm using Dynamoid ORM (https://github.com/Dynamoid/Dynamoid). When i instantiate the Video class in my local environment (with operations such as Video.new or Video.build) it works perfectly but when i deploy the application to Heroku the same operations fail with the error in the following image.

[image: can't dup FalseClass]

I've been googling the error but i haven't found anything to solve my problem. This is the only model/class with this problem, the others work fine.

Here are my Video model and Video controller.

**Video Class**

```
class Video
    include Dynamoid::Document
    table :name => :videos, :key => :id, :read_capacity => 5, :write_capacity => 5
    field :nombre
    field :apellido
    field :email
    field :titulo
    field :descripcion
    field :video_source
    field :estado, :boolean, {default: false}

    belongs_to :concurso

end
```

And my **VideoController::create**

```
def create
    concurso = params[:video]
    concurso_id = concurso[:id]
    @concurso = Concurso.find(concurso_id)
    @video = Video.new(:nombre => params[:nombre], :apellido =>  params[:apellido], :email => params[:email], :titulo => params[:titulo], :descripcion => params[:descripcion], :video_source => params[:video_source].original_filename)
    @video.concurso = @concurso
    respond_to do |format|
        if  @video.save
            format.html { redirect_to @video, notice: 'Video was successfully created.' }
            format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @video }
        else
            format.html { render :new }
            format.json { render json: @video.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
    end
end
```

Does anyone know what could be the problem?

Thanks,

Comment: what's the value of this  params[:video_source].original_filename

Comment: @gates params[:video_source] contains the temporal video file object that gets uploaded, and the .original_filename gives me the name of that file.